# Razor views using in Visual Studio 2019 are not updating

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, refresh, visual-studio-2019

When I create a fresh asp.net project, updates to my razor views are not being reflected when I refresh the browser.

They are only updated when I halt the debug session and start the server again. Very annoying.
I have turned off network caching and have tried this with Chrome and Internet Explorer. The problem persists.

Old projects created with .net 2.2 work fine, this only affects new projects created in .net 3.0.

Answer (score 7):

The problem seems to be a bug in visual studio. Here is a work around:

1) Add the NuGet package *Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation*

2) Modify the **ConfigureServices** method in **startup.cs**

Replace

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

with

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

This should fix the problem. I noticed that refreshes are now quite slow but quicker than restarting the server everytime.

Answer (score 0):

**Enable Razor runtime compilation** as shown below when creating new ASP.NET CORE 3.1 project: I am using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7.6 with ASP.NET MVC CORE 3.1:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer of @ian-gibblet for the **Web App** type of projects. 
Go to Startup.cs, modify the function **ConfigureServices** and add

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

your function will be like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
}
```

Hopefully it will resolve the issues of **Web App** type of projects.
(It is working fine with .net core 3.1 projects)